# responseBody is not defined in Postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have JSON like below:

```json
{
    "success": true,
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Success",
    "data": [
        {
            "ID_A": "AXCS-1-1",
            "ID_B": "AXCS-1-1",
            "Number": "11009988"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my script for testing in postman:

```js
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);

if(responseCode.code === 200){
    pm.environment.set("IdA",data.data[0].ID_A);
    pm.environment.set("IdB",data.data[0].ID_B);
}
```

And I get the response:

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: you have a typo: `data.code` not `responseCode.code`

Comment: Thats don't work when i change `data.code` from `responseCode.code`

Comment: Just a general question, why have you used `JSON.parse(responseBody)` in the script? Have you followed a tutorial? Do you know about `pm.response.json()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error says responseBody is not defined and the error is from prerequest script

responseBody is a global object that contains the response , this variable is available only in test script , and as pre-request is executed before the request is even send, requestBody variable wont be accessible

Comment: Thanks, i wrong put my scripts in pre-request not in test